# How to automatically backup snapshots/images in Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I have Google Compute Engine instances and I want to do automatic snapshot/image backups.
It should be like a schedule job that every 5 hours it makes a snapshot/image to my instances.

I read that it is possible to do with Cron job but I can't understand how to do it.

Could you please help me to understand how to do automatic snapshot/image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an .sh script to make the snapshot with the gcloud command. This is the script we are using:

```
# Settings
GCLOUD_PROJECT="my-project"
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON="location to service account json"
DISK_NAME="my-disk"
GCE_ZONE="europe-west1-d"
DATETIME=`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"`

# authenticate first
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON --project $GCLOUD_PROJECT 

# sync => empty filesystem buffers
sync

# make the actual snapshot
gcloud --project $GCLOUD_PROJECT compute disks snapshot $DISK_NAME --zone $GCE_ZONE --snapshot-names $DISK_NAME-$DATETIME
```

This will create a new incremental snapshot every time you run (for example create a cron to run it at night). The next thing you need to do is to decide how many snapshots you want to keep. We are keeping 5 snapshots and created the next script to delete the snapshots older then the 5 most recent snapshots. We run this script 30 mins after the first one to make sure that the creation of the snapshot is finished.

```
# Settings
GCLOUD_PROJECT="my-project"
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON="location to service account json"
DISK_NAME="my-disk"
GCE_ZONE="europe-west1-d"

# authenticate first
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON --project $GCLOUD_PROJECT

# list snapshots
snapshot_list=($(gcloud --project $GCLOUD_PROJECT compute snapshots list --sort-by NAME --regexp "$DISK_NAME-.*" | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1}'))

keep_index=$(expr ${#snapshot_list[*]} - 5)

for i in $(seq 0 $keep_index);
do
    gcloud --project $GCLOUD_PROJECT compute snapshots delete ${snapshot_list[i]} -q
done
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be useful for me. Could you please explain how to connect the sh file with cron? I mean, I created this sh file but how do I tell Google to run it every X hours? Should I run this script in gcloud?
I am new to Google Cloud and I am confused where to start... This code helps but how to do the other steps you described, could you please decribe more?

Comment: gcloud is the command line tool for running jobs in the Google Cloud Platform. It should already be installed on Linux instances started in GCP. Simply type gcloud on the command line to test it. To authorise your jobs you will need to create a service account with the correct priviliges. You can create one in the console under IAM.

Comment: Regarding the cron, you can add a new cron with the command "crontab -e". You will need to add a line like this: 0 */5 * * * /command/to/run  If you want to know the details about possibilities and options of cron then there are many guides on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Google has now introduced the `Snapshot Scheduler`. You can find it in the snapshot section -> Create Snapshot Schedule.

Once you have the schedule you can create a new disk and select the schedule or edit an existing this and assign the scheduler.